# Manage Hfile with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, hfile

I want to know if there is a possibility to charge HFile in RDD or Dataframe in PySPark ?
In order to charge each HFile as csv file for instance.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In Java (and Scala by extension), you would read HFile content using `HFile.Reader` to create an `HFileScanner` (https://hbase.apache.org/2.3/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/hfile/HFile.Reader.html#getScanner-boolean-boolean-) and then iterate through it. Not sure if pyspark / python has anything similar.